# What is the structure of Standard Interchange Format (SIF) used by spatial data providers?

Tags: java, c++, php, format, c

What is the structure of Standard Interchange Format(SIF) used by navteq and other spatial data providers? Any documentation/sample files? Is there a SIF parser available in C/C++/Java/PHP ?